# How can I extract AutoIt script from PE binaries fast in Python

Tags: python, autoit, portable-executable

I have lot's of PE binaries to analyse, some of them are malicious, some of them are not, but we can know that there's AutoIt Script and other resource (such as .exe/.jpg/.dll) in the compiled binary, I am trying to extract this resource out from these binaries.

Currently I am using the tool called: [AutoIt-Ripper](https://github.com/nazywam/AutoIt-Ripper), well, it can get the job done, but the performance is quite slow, some binary can be extracted within seconds, some binary can take even 20 mins.

here's some samples:

[image: Some samples]

some of the code block:

```
from autoit_ripper import extract, AutoItVersion

def extract_autoit(path_name):
    with open(path_name, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()

    data = extract(data=file_data, version=AutoItVersion.EA06)
    output_path = f"output/{path_name.split('/')[-1]}"
    if data:
        output = Path(output_path)
        if not output.is_dir():
            log.info("The output directory doesn't exist, creating it")
            output.mkdir()

        for filename, content in data:
            filename = basename(filename)
            log.info(f"Storing result in {(output / filename).as_posix()}")
            (output / filename).write_bytes(content)
```

The [AutoIt-Ripper](https://github.com/nazywam/AutoIt-Ripper) can extract the AutoIt script within seconds if the binary only contain AutoIt Script, but if the binary contain more than that, it could take ages

I am looking for some help, to reduce the decompile time, looking for average decompile maybe in seconds level.

Comment: The bottleneck is probably how fast the `autoit_ripper.extract()` runs, so you would need to speed it up, not your driver script.

Comment: Yes, the bottleneck is the AutoIt-Ripper, I am looking for alternative tool that can extract it faster.